# Which linux os can be used to install and run windows-based programs/software?

Tags: operating-system

i am searching for an OS [preferably linux-based] that i can use to install and run applications that are usually run in windows. does anyone know of such an OS

Answer (score 0):

You can install what ever linux version you want and than install Wine.
Wine is a free and open-source app which allows us to install and run Windows applications on Linux. To be a bit more technical, Wine is a compatibility layer; it translates the Windows system calls to Linux and uses some Windows libraries, in the form of .dll files.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like [WINE](https://www.winehq.org/) to run Windows programs on Linux. It doesn't matter which Linux distro you will use.